# How do I check if Windows Installer 3.1 or higher is installed?

Tags: windows-installer

I need to know this since this is a pre-req for .NET 3.5 and if I'm including the .NET bootstrapper, I should also see if Windows Installer 3.1 is needed.

Right now I'm checking for the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Windows XP\SP3\KB893803v2
```

Which will check for Windows Installer 3.1 but I suspect it doesn't check for higher versions. (Haven't been able to confirm or deny that)

What registry key should I look at to find this information?

Edit: I need to check this in Inno Setup which is what I'm using as my bootstrapper, and I'm not sure how to check a dll version in there.

Comment: wow... this question got me the Famous Question gold badge (10k views) and still only 1 upvote.  There should be another badge for that :p

Comment: Welcome to the world of installers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

locate the installer msi.dll with this registry path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer

value: InstallerLocation

then get the version information from that file.

update:
the way above is old!
new way to detect the version is documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368280%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Be mindful of redirects on 64-bit systems... which msi file you're directed to will depend on whether your app is running 32 or 64 bit mode.  That said, however, the 32 and 64 bit versions of the windows installer *should* be the same on any 64-bit system.

Comment: at least on win32 systems this is just the location, msiexec.exe is the file name. Right click -> Properties -> Version

Comment: the way i described, was the official way documented in msdn (in dec.08 -> see http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/09/09/458528.aspx).
they updated the best practices to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368280%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 13):

On the "Run" window, type "msiexec".  A window will come up showing the Windows Installer version on the first line.

Comment: How is that supposed to be parsed from Inno Setup?

Comment: +1 very easy way to find out the exact version non-progrmmatically. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check the version of the Windows Installer on your system,  **check the version of *MSI.DLL* in the Windows\System 32 folder.**

Right click on MSI.DLL , select properties -> go to Details tab and check file version.

Comment: +1 I used sigcheck.exe from sysinternals to check this. sigcheck c:\windows\system32\msi.dll

Comment: It is `system32` not `System 32`. And that directory doesn't have to be under a directory called `windows`. Better checkout dynamically e.g. using `%systemroot%` where your system32 might be.

Answer (score 1):

If this is inside the MSI file itself, you can check for the [VersionMsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372493(VS.85).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this link](http://www.pitribe.com/posts.aspx?id=2603.1467569276_check-windows-installer-version) may help you as already **works for me** for **Windows 7**, hopefully may work for other versions of **windows** as well to check Windows Installer version.